# How can I change a walkspeed to like a variable

Tags: roblox

```
local playerName = OykkoIsBack
Players.(playerName).Character.Humanoid.JumpPower = 100
```

so I want to set my jump power to the variable that has the players name? im new to roblox
scripting and this happened in my output

```
Expected identifier, got '('
```

something similar to this happened
i wrote this if game.Workspace.IntValue.Value = 0 then
print("Value is 0")
but i figured this out by adding a another = but this time i can't figure it out so i need someone to help me!
really appreciate it if you could help me!

Answer (score 1):

`OykkoIsBack` should have double quotes around it, so the first line should be `local playerName = "OykkoIsBack"`. Without the quotes, it is not a string and cannot be assigned to playerName.

The other issue is with `Players.(playerName)`. The syntax for indexing a table in Lua is `table[key]`. In your case it should be `Players[playerName]`

Here is the code

```
local playerName = "OykkoIsBack"
Players[playerName].Character.Humanoid.JumpPower = 100
```

What this does is sets `playerName` to `OykkoIsBack`, then it gets the humanoid of the player with `playerName` and sets their jump power to 100.

Answer (score 0):

I’m quite new at scripting too, so I might be wrong but here’s what I think the mistake is:

First of all you put

```
Players.(playername).Character.Humanoid etc.
```

I think ‘playername’ shouldn’t have brackets?

Secondly, you just set the jumpPower to 100?? Try replacing the 100 with a variable, so after the = try writing the variable name.

I think this because the error is saying there was a bracket where it expected something else (from what I know) so I think it’s just the playername brackets.